# Sunspot and Rsolr query

Tags: solr, sunspot, rsolr

I'm reading sunspot documentation and find that sunspot based on RSolr library.
Is there any way to get connection to perform low level request like this
pseudo-code:

```
solr = Sunspot.connection
response = solr.get 'select', :params => {:q => '*:*'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as of the current version (1.3.2). Well, you can, but you'd have to `instance_eval` a few objects to get to the underlying RSolr object. Patches are welcome at http://github.com/sunspot/sunspot — a good accessor method for the RSolr connection would be welcome.

Comment: Is there an update to this issue? I'm also searching for a way to access the RSolr connection from Sunspot.